# CSS Pseudo Selector: Active After Pseudo: Hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the blue line that is appearing on hover to stay when the link is active. I am building an angular app with a few different views and when the user is active on a view, I would like the underline I have created on hover, to stay when the link is selected. I assume it needs to take on an active pseudo selector, but when I've added it in, it cancels the hover. Any suggestions on this would be much appreciated.

Here is my current code:

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 0 60px;
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
}
footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ABABAB;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: #00FFE9;
}
.nav-footer {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px #DEDEDE;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <nav class="nav-footer">
    <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="friends">View Friends</a>
    <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="friend-search">Find Friends</a>
    <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="update">Update Profile</a>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uw8fqbyr/

Comment: did you try `a:active{text-decoration:underline;}`

Comment: @AatifBandey that just seems to add another little gray line above the blue one I have set to appear on hover.

Comment: Did my answer help you? you can make use of `visited`

Comment: Use .active class for link active state. 
Here is the fiddle update https://jsfiddle.net/uw8fqbyr/2/

Comment: @AatifBandey it did help and it seems to work as well. It seems there are many ways. Thank you.

Comment: @TalonHughes can you tick mark the answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ui-sref-active="active" directive adds "active" css class to a tag when selected view is active.

You should add this css rule

```
a.active:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: #00FFE9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with

```
a:active:after {}
```

you can enable the text decoration for your anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Try 
   `a:active{}`

for the `<a>` tag visited

`a:visited{}`

Answer (score 1):

Try below

```css
footer {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 0 60px;
  font-family: "Lora", serif;
}

footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ABABAB;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}

a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: #00FFE9;
}
a.active:after {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #00FFE9;
}

.nav-footer {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-top: solid 2px #DEDEDE;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
        <nav class="nav-footer">
   <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="friends">View Friends</a>
    <a class="active" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="friend-search">Find Friends</a>
   <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="update">Update Profile</a>
  </nav>
  </footer>
```

Comment: I like this one too! Thanks! It works well and the underline isn't as thick as the hover so the user can tell there is a subtle difference.

Comment: @TalonHughes Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add below code link never show underline on `active` state
`a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}`